# Calling manual subscription on declaration in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I realize the point of a computed or manual subscription is to track changes to observables. However, I've run into a situation where I need a manual subscription to run as soon as it's declared, instead of waiting for the observable to change.

Is there a way to tell a subscription to run once immediately?

Example:

```
vm.foo = ko.observable("bar");
vm.foo.subscribe(function() {
    // code i want to run immediately, and on every observable change
});
```

AFAIK, the subscription will only run if `vm.foo` changes, but I have code I need to run against it as soon as the app boots up.

Comment: Can you provide sample code, so it is easier to understand what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function `valueHasMutated` on `observable` to notify all subscribers that there was a change in observable:

```
var vm = {};
vm.foo = ko.observable("bar");
vm.foo.subscribe(function() {
    console.log('runs!');
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.foo.valueHasMutated();    // you see 'runs!' printed in console output
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmy56zbx/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating your own 'subscribeAndRun' method which is incredibly useful and will not cause unintended side-effects and performance issues from using valueHasMutated() which notifies any and all subscribers.

Typescript:

```
function subcribeAndRun<T>(o: KnockoutObservable<T>,callback: (v: T) => void): KnockoutObservable<T> {
    o.subscribe(callback);
    callback(o());
    return o;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function subcribeAndRun(o, callback) {
    o.subscribe(callback);
    callback(o());
    return o;
}
```